# Want a 3v led to operate when 12v is applied

Tags: power-supply, led, voltage

I have a circuit with 6v and 12v. There is 1 diode between the two positives so when 12v is turned on it does not run through the 6v circuit. What I need is the led to only come on when the 12v supply is on. At the moment if the 12v feed is not on I have 6v coming through in witch the led turn's on. I only need the led to turn on when the 12v feed is turned on.

Comment: So put a series resistor that the extra voltage will drop on it.

Comment: So when the 12V supply isn't on but the 6V one is, the  6V will power the 12V rail at about 5.3V?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your question, but apparently you have a 6 V power feed and a 12 V power feed to a circuit, and you only want a LED to come one when the 12 V feed is active, not the 6 V feed.  And there is a diode from the 6 V feed to 12 V feed?

I guess you're asking the question because if you put a resistor in series with the LED sized to get the brightness you want when 12 V is applied, you still get too much brightness when 6 V is applied.

There are two relatively easy ways to deal with this:

Put another diode, preferably a Schottky, in series with the 12 V supply and run the LED off the voltage before the diode.

Use a transistor as a threshold detector set to around 9 V so that it is on at 12 V but off at 6 V, and run the LED thru the transistor.

Answer (score 0):

One or two diodes?  If there is only a single diode between the +6V input and the 12V input *and* the 12V input directly feeds the load, it will be difficult (but not impossible) to detect when only the 12V supply is ON.  However, if you have *two* diodes: one diode in series with each supply input, it's easy.

Simply connect the indicator LED and current-limit resistor *before* the diode summing network for whichever input you want.  You could have two indicators if you want: one for the 12V input and another for the 6V input.  The diodes stop the one power supply input from backfeeding the other.

Answer (score 0):

Put a Zener diode with reverse bias in series with the LED. Say you have a 2 V LED, you can put a 5.1 V Zener in series and it will only turn on when you get more than 7.1 V.